# Linux - reverse proxy - What is the easiest tool for powerful reverse proxy?

Tags: linux, debian, reverse-proxy

I am setting up a domain with a set of URLs per customer (customerx.domain.com) on a set of Debian servers.

What is the best tool to redirect incoming requests to different servers and/or different services on the same server depending on some request parameters?

For example :

```
https://generic.domain.com/redir?customer=1&name=x
```

would be redirected to

```
https://customerx.domain.com/app1?name=x
```

and

```
https://generic.domain.com/redir?customer=2&name=x
```

would be redirected to

```
https://customery.domain.com/app2?name=x
```

Comment: I know for a fact that it would be difficult in apache2 with mod_proxy and its configuration complications. I'm hoping someone will come with an obviously easier solution

Comment: In a way this is a good question, however it is likely to be closed as subjective. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nginx](http://nginx.com/) is a widely used and powerful HTTP server with strong [proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) capabilities.

Comment: I know it's very late to accept this answer. But this is what I ended up to do, very successfully.